# How to use awk to get the result of computation of column1 value of the same column2 value in 2 csv files in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, csv, ubuntu, awk

I am using ubuntu and we got a csv file1.csv with 2 columns looks like

```
a,1
b,2
c,3
...
```

and another file2.csv with 2 columns looks like

```
a,4
b,3
d,2
...
```

Some of column 1 value appear in file1.csv but not in file2.csv and vice cersa and these values should not be in result.csv. Say the value of first column in file1.csv is x and the value of first column in file2.csv with the same column2 value is y. How to use awk to compute (x-y)/(x+y) of second lines of 2 csv files in Ubuntu to get the result.csv like this:

```
a,-0.6
b,-0.2
```

-0.6 is computed by (1-4)/(1+4)
-0.2 is computed by (2-3)/(2+3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next} {if ($1 in a) print $1,(a[$1]-$2)/(a[$1]+$2)}' f1 f2
a,-0.6
b,-0.2
```

#### Explanation

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` set input and output field separators as comma.
- `FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next}` when processinig first file, store in the array `a[]` the values like `a[first col]=second col`.
- `{if ($1 in a) print $1,(a[$1]-$2)/(a[$1]+$2)}` when looping through second file, on each line do: check if the first col is stored in the `a[]` array; if so, print `(x-y)/(x+y)`, being `x=stored value` and `y=current second column`.